# Exclude Zeros From Array of String

Tags: c#, linq

I've a list of strings as follows:

```
A:2
B:2
C:0
D:0
```

I am trying to exclude the values with zeroes, so expected output should be as follows:

```
A:2
B:2
```

I tried something as follows and got an exception as well:

```
foreach (var item in charCnt.OrderBy(q => q).ToList().RemoveAll(p => p.Contains("0")))
{
    concat += item + ", "; //Concatenate items from the list
}
```

Exception:

**foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'int' because 'int' does not contain a public instance or extension definition for 'GetEnumerator'**

I know, this seems pretty basic as the statement says. Any way I can rid of the above using simple statement?

**Updated 1**:

```
 List<string> charCnt = new List<string> { "A:1", "C:-1", "C:1", "B:1", "B:1", "D:-2" "A:1", "D:2" };
```

**Updated 2**:
Here's the tried one: [Sample Code](https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ppq254)

Comment: I don't see where you're using a foreach, but your sample does nothing - you are creating a list, rmoving items, then _not using the list that was created_.

Comment: Your code would also filter out rows that contained `"10"` - I'd suggest looking up `string.split` to see how to get the number part of each string.

Comment: Updated @DStanley. Though my idea is to remove all starting zeros.

Comment: What is the type of the elements of `charCnt`? Are they really strings, as in "A:2", "C:0", etc.?

Comment: `List.RemoveAll` returns an `int`. That is why you get that message.

Comment: After the update, do they *really* have to be strings, or could they be key:value pairs? Or anything other than strings that hide that there are two parts? A tuple, a class instance, anything other than a string?

Comment: I've updated my code sample. Please check.

Comment: @user8512043 OK, so you want to sum the values for each A, B, C, etc. With the code as shown, you are making it difficult for yourself. Where does the data come from?

Comment: Done. Thanks to all. The answer helped with this statement - `charCnt.RemoveAll(p => p.Contains(":0"));`. I missed this part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably you want:

```
var orderedList = charCnt.OrderBy(q => q).ToList();
orderedList.RemoveAll(p => p.Contains("0")); // maybe change "0" to '0' ?
var concatenedString = string.Join (", ", orderedList);
```

Comment: I'd update that contains to be `":0"` to handle 10, 20, etc

Comment: Got it. Thanks for this line of code - `charCnt.RemoveAll(p => p.Contains(":0"));`.